# Intent not returning score?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm creating a simple android game but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here due to being new to android. The first bit of code I have is in the `GameView` class and returns an integer for how many times a sprite is pressed:

```
public int getHitCount() {
    return hitCount;

}
```

It is then returned to the `GameActivity` class where an intent receives it and then it is supposed to go to the main menu class, I think I've got it being sent to the `GameActivity` class correctly but I'm not sure why the score is not returned to the main menu. Here is my `GameActivity` intent:

```
public void finish(){
    super.finish();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,MainMenu.class);
    returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE",gameView.getHitCount());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

    }

    }
```

Here is the code I use to display it on the `MainMenu`class but it isn't working for some reason:

```
 if (requestCode == SCORE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (retIntent.hasExtra("GAME_SCORE")) {
                int scoreFromGame = retIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");
                tvScore.setText(""+Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));


            }
        }   

public void startGame(View v){
    gameIntent = new Intent(this,GameActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(gameIntent, SCORE_REQUEST_CODE );  
}
```

Comment: What's being returned as score? Nothing, 0 or what?

Comment: @GeorgeR It just returns a 0 no matter what score is gotten in the game.

Comment: Are you sure that `GameActivity` successfully gets the value?  Add a log entry to be sure.

Comment: Try to use the Log to check where is the error. Use Log.w("score", ""+value); before sending it through the intent to see if the problem is only when you receive it on the other side. The Log will apear on LogCat, you know how it works?

Comment: I checked the log and I got this: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {cct.mad.lab/cct.mad.lab.MainMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: If there's a line numer on the error description take a look and put the code and the full error message on your question so we can check that.

Comment: @GeorgeR how would I find the line number if there is one?

Comment: Try taking all of your `setResult()` code out of `finish()`, and put it somewhere else.

Comment: @DanielNugent I've tried that and it didn't do anything, is there anywhere specific I should put it?

Comment: @DanielNugent as far as I can tell there is nowhere else in the class to put it

Comment: Somewhere that will be ran after you get the score from `GameView `.

Comment: Maybe just put the super.finish(); after the intent. Does setResult starts the next activity?

Comment: @GeorgeR if I put super.finish() after the intent it causes it to crash when I try to go back to the main menu

Comment: @DanielNugent if I put it anywhere else I get an error saying: returnIntent cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @MichaelFassbender Use the Log as we said so you can see you're sending the right value.
Try also: myIntent.getExtraInt(VARIABLE) instead.

Comment: @GeorgeR sorry I'm not good with the log how would I go about getting the info you need?

Comment: Put a line on the code like this one: Log.e("Score", SCORE_VARIABLE);
Then look in the logcat for this line and see if the result is right. the line will be red. Use this on the game activity before you send it to the intent.

Comment: I put that there, it's saying I don't have SCORE_VARIABLE should I make it equal hitcount from the gameview class?

Comment: Yes, use there the hitcount.

Comment: @GeorgeR I get this when I try that: The method e(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, int). Here's what I have it set as:   Log.e("Score", gameView.getHitCount());

Answer (score 1):

The intent you use to return stuff is just a plain intent - no need to set a target component

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
```

It's fine.

Also, try to do `setResult()` **before** calling finish - rather in an overridden finish.
You need to override something, do it in the `onDestroy()`

Also, you need to make sure to use `startActivityForResult()` to start the Activity hosting GameView.

Comment: Sorry, where should these go? this has completely confused me why it's not working

Comment: I can assure you that setResult() works even from outside finish() - because I use it in my own app :)
Actually I would try to make sure to do it before calling any finish().

Comment: So Would I create a new class for these?

Comment: I understand you got two activities `GameActivity` and `MainMenu`.

So first thing, make sure you start GameActivity from MainMenu with startActivityForResult().

The moment you realize that GameActivity has to end and return to MainMenu - let's say in an onClick() method - you go
`    onClick() {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE",gameView.getHitCount());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish()
    }`

It's diffucult to write code in the comments :/ make sure you follow my answer

Comment: I just updated to show that startActivityForResult is already in there.

Comment: Whenever I try to put the intent outside of the finish it causes the game to crash when pressing the back button